# Find MongoDB document from id posted as hidden input

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

How can I find the document matching the ID being posted in a hidden input?

Here is my schema:

```
var MessageSchema = Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    message: {type: String, required: true},
    replies: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
}, {timestamps: true});
```

Here is my form:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) { %>
  <form action="/comment/create" method="post">
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="name" name="name">
        <label>Comment: </label>
        <input type="text" name="comment">
        <input type="hidden" name="replyTo" value=<%= messages[i]['_id']%> >
        <button>Reply</button>
  </form>
<% } %>
```

And my post route is a mess so at this point I just want to know how to find the dang message.

```
app.post('/comment/create', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.replyTo);   
    var message = Message.find({ _id: req.body.replyTo }); 
    console.log(message);
    res.redirect('/');
})
```

console.log(req.body.replyTo) returns the id 59022ff22951ce73ed9bb773.
console.log(message) returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `Messages.find` is asynchronous, and therefore will not provide a proper value when assigning it's result to the variable `message`. You need to handle this either with a callback or a Promise:

**As a callback**

```
Message.find({ _id: req.body.replyTo }, (err, res) => {
  console.log(res); // message
});
```

**As a Promise**

```
Message.find({ _id: req.body.replyTo })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res); // message
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // ...
  });
```